# Solving MINLP with Pyomo. Is there any setting about 'Starting feasible solution'?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

My environment is: Python 3.5.2, Anaconda 4.2.0 (32-bit), Pyomo 4.4.1 (VOTD) (CPython 3.5.2 on W7), Baron 17.3.31

I'm currently doing optimization with Pyomo and Baron as the solver. For testing, a minlp problem is used. I can get the optimal solution by running the main.py code as following. Every time I run the code, after the first-time run, I will get the same solution as the first-time run. The result will show:

> Starting solution is feasible with a value of     xxxxx
>   Doing local search
>   Solving bounding LP
>   Starting multi-start local search
>   Done with local search

The starting feasible solution will be the same every time.

However, after I restart the kernel(restart the Spyder) and run the file again, it might get the different solution. WHY? Is there any method to reset optimization process? How can I get the various solution without restarting the kernel?

I'v done some try: imp.reload(pyomo.environ), imp.reload(pyomo.opt)...etc

Please help. Thank you.

The main file main.py is as below:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
from minlp import model


instance = model.create_instance()
instance.dual = Suffix(direction=Suffix.IMPORT)
minlpopt = SolverFactory("baron")
results = minlpopt.solve(instance, tee=True)
print('Objective Fucntion: ' + str(instance.obj()))
```

The model file minlp.py is as below:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

# SETS ========================================================================
model = ConcreteModel()

model.y1 = Var(within=Binary)
model.y2 = Var(within=Binary)
model.y3 = Var(within=Binary)
model.x1 = Var(within=PositiveReals, bounds=(0,2))
model.x2 = Var(within=PositiveReals, bounds=(0,2))
model.x3 = Var(within=PositiveReals, bounds=(0,1))


# RULE ========================================================================
def obj_rule(model):
    return (5 * model.y1 + 6 * model.y2 + 8 * model.y3 + 10 * model.x1 \
            - 7 * model.x3 - 18 * log(model.x2 + 1) \
            - 19.2 * log(model.x1 - model.x2 + 1) + 10)
model.obj = Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=minimize)


def c1_rule(model):
    return (0.8 * log(model.x2 + 1) + 0.96 * log(model.x1 - model.x2 + 1) \
            - 0.8 * model.x3) >= 0
model.c1 = Constraint(rule=c1_rule)

def c2_rule(model):
    return (log(model.x2 + 1) + 1.2 * log(model.x1 - model.x2 + 1) - model.x3 \
            - 2 * model.y3) >= -2
model.c2 = Constraint(rule=c2_rule)

def c3_rule(model):
    return model.x2 - model.x1 <= 0
model.c3 = Constraint(rule=c3_rule)

def c4_rule(model):
    return model.x2 - 2 * model.y1 <= 0
model.c4 = Constraint(rule=c4_rule)

def c5_rule(model):
    return model.x1 - model.x2 - 2 * model.y2 <= 0
model.c5 = Constraint(rule=c5_rule)

def c6_rule(model):
    return model.y1 + model.y2 <= 1
model.c6 = Constraint(rule=c6_rule)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `keepfiles=True` to the `solve()` call, it will print out the temporary `.bar` file that is sent to Baron (note that we also support the NL file interface to Baron, which requires the `baron_ampl` solver). Also, adding `symbolic_solver_labels=True` will make this file a little easier to read by using the original names of objects on the model to write the file.

I would recommend diff-ing these files at each iteration for different runs. If, for instance, the `.bar` file at the first iteration is the same for two different runs but the solutions are different after that iteration, it means that the non-deterministic behavior is inside Baron (perhaps there is a Baron option to control this). Otherwise, look for places in your code where iteration order might change from run to run, which might cause different results for certain operations (e.g., places where you iterate over the keys of a dictionary).

The default behavior of the Pyomo solvers is usually sufficient to make output files look the same for models that are equivalent. If this is not the case, it is likely because objects are not being added to parent blocks in the same order. In this case, you can try adding `file_determinism=3` to the `solve()` call for file-based solvers. This will cause some additional sorting to occur before the file is written, which ensures that the output file always looks the same.